# flask: how to bridge front-end with back-end service to render api authentication?

Tags: python, api, flask

In [flask-restplus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), I want to render API authentication view for my minimal flask API, where whenever when I make a request to the server, the first API should pop up a protective view for asking the user to provide customized token value before using API call. I came up my solution to make API authentication pop view before using api function, but couldn't get that correctly. Can anyone help me out how to make my code work smooth? Any idea?

**My current attempt with full implementation**:

Here is the partial code of my implementation to do this task.

```
from functools import wraps
import requests, json, psycopg2, datetime
from time import time
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api, abort, fields, inputs, reqparse
from itsdangerous import SignatureExpired, JSONWebSignatureSerializer, BadSignature


class AuthenticationToken:
    def __init__(self, secret_key, expires_in):
        self.secret_key = secret_key
        self.expires_in = expires_in
        self.serializer = JSONWebSignatureSerializer(secret_key)

    def generate_token(self, username):
        info = {
            'username': username,
            'creation_time': time()
        }

        token = self.serializer.dumps(info)
        return token.decode()

    def validate_token(self, token):
        info = self.serializer.loads(token.encode())

        if time() - info['creation_time'] > self.expires_in:
            raise SignatureExpired("The Token has been expired; get a new token")

        return info['username']


SECRET_KEY = "f4b58245-6fd4-4bce-a8a4-27ca37370a3c"
expires_in = 600
auth = AuthenticationToken(SECRET_KEY, expires_in)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I pretty much coded up all for API authentication but couldn't get the authentication pop view that I expected in my desired output.

**Update: output at server endpoint**:

When I tried `http://127.0.0.1:5000/token` at server endpoint, I got `Not Found` error. How can I get my desired output? any idea?

I am wondering how can I get api protection view that requires a token to access API. currently, I have an error, couldn't get my desired output, so I am hopeful `SO` community helps me through with this.

**desired output**:

I want to render a protective view for test API before using API call on the server endpoint. Here is a mockup API authorization view that I want to get:

[image]

how can I make this happen using python flask, flask restful? any thought? thanks

Comment: this may [help](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6/authorization.html)

Comment: correct me if i am wrong about what i understand, you have login into a system and want to make a communication with the server for this you want to use an authentication key, using this authentication key if successful you want to make the communication with the server for valid user  otherwise reject it right ?

Comment: all u  need to do is save tokens in code for different user in a dict or db and create a function which check the token provided by  u exist in that tokens dict or not if  yes then authorized

Comment: sorry for full implementation it will be too much code for me(i hate doing ui )you can consider this as write a function which take token as input, check the token against a token dictionary if present then add the value associated with that token as key give user or return True markimg user is authenticated

Comment: Can you elaborate on your further server setup? Any specific reason why you do not rely on established, out-of the box authentication mechanisms? If not, I would suggest to use one of the frameworks which are already implemented and tested like https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or even thirdparty services with multi-factor authentication.

Comment: @B--rian do yo have any thought including coding attempt on my backend service code that I wrote? any possible attempt from you would be helpful. thanks

Comment: I *did* read your code, and I see 2 functions `generate_token()` and `validate_token()`. (a) Are those two ready and working as they should? There seem to be 2 hurdles which do not allow me to answer you properly: (b) I am unsure which architecture you have in mind - maybe you could make a quick sketch and edit in into your question. (c) As [Matt L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551945/matt-l) points out, you seem to ask for a full recipe for token-authentication. I suggest that add a paragraph emphasizing your must burning issue. All the follow-up, we could do in another SO-question.

Comment: I meant *most burning* not *must burning*, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured what you are doing, and @B--rian, @Matt L. mentioned above, it is not one-shot task that `SO` community would give help all code base. But this is what I did and I would guide you how you can finish you task with some pains.

we can try to solve this task by dividing several steps, but let's come around this step, I am gonna post nest one shortly:

```
from functools import wraps
from time import time
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from flask_restplus import abort
from flask_restplus import fields
from flask_restplus import inputs
from flask_restplus import reqparse
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
import psycopg2, datetime, requests, json
from itsdangerous import SignatureExpired, JSONWebSignatureSerializer, BadSignature

'''
## to get API security key, to do:
import uuid
print(str(uuid.uuid4()))
'''

class AuthenticationToken(object):
    def __init__(self, secret_key, expires_in):
        self.secret_key = secret_key
        self.expires_in = expires_in
        self.serializer = JSONWebSignatureSerializer(secret_key)

    def generate_token(self, username):
        info = {
            'username': username,
            'creation_time': time()
        }
        token = self.serializer.dumps(info)
        return token.decode()

    def validate_token(self, token):
        info = self.serializer.loads(token.encode())

        if time() - info['creation_time'] > self.expires_in:
            raise SignatureExpired("The Token has been expired; get a new token")

        return info['username']

SECRET_KEY = "f4b58245-6fd4-4bce-a8a4-27ca37370a3c"
expires_in = 600
auth = AuthenticationToken(SECRET_KEY, expires_in)

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app,authorizations={
                'API-KEY': {
                    'type': 'apiKey',
                    'in': 'header',
                    'name': 'AUTH-TOKEN'
                }
            },
          security='API-KEY',
          default="API AUTH TOKEN", 
          title="immunoMatch RESTful API", 
          description="Immunomatch ED API Authentication View") 

db = psycopg2.connect(database='test_db', user='postgres', password='password', host='localhost', port="5432")

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):

        token = request.headers.get('AUTH-TOKEN')
        if not token:
            abort(401, 'Authentication token is missing')

        try:
            user = auth.validate_token(token)
        except SignatureExpired as e:
            abort(401, e.message)
        except BadSignature as e:
            abort(401, e.message)

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

credential_model = api.model('credential', {
    'username': fields.String(required=True),
    'password': fields.String(required=True)
})

credential_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
credential_parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
credential_parser.add_argument('password', type=str)

@api.route('/token')
class Token(Resource):
    @api.expect(credential_parser, validate=True)
    def get(self):
        args = credential_parser.parse_args()
        username = args.get('username')
        password = args.get('password')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM public.authorized_user_table')
        user = cursor.fetchone()

        if username != user[1]:
            api.abort(404, "Username: {} doesn't exist".format(username))
        if password != user[2]:
            api.abort(401, "Wrong password")
        return {"token": auth.generate_token(username)}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = psycopg2.connect(database='test_db', user='postgres', password='password', host='localhost', port="5432")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I suggest try to digest what @B--rian, @Matt L mentioned in their post, I think @Matt L did point out something worthy you should think of, their advice is nice except not much coding attempt was given. but I would come back to you as soon as I figured out rest.

Comment: thanks for heads up. I am gonna try it. Can you guide me how to get over with it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggest, there's no simple snippet of code anyone can share to answer this question. You're basically asking for a five-part blog on how to attach a database to a Flask app in order to authenticate API credentials. I know it doesn't seem this way, but your questions really cascade from one topic Yinto the next. I think your best bet is to  look at the Flask Mega Tutorial [Part IV Databases](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) and [Part V User Logins](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins). These tutorials cover the foundational concepts your code seems to be missing, as follows:

1. Using [SQLalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to define your database models
2. Defining a basic authorization table in your DB
3. Using encryption so that your authorization tokens can't be lifted from the database
4. Flushing expired tokens from the auth table
5. Using pre-built methods to validate authorization such as [Flask-Github's github-callback example](https://github-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Flask-Login's](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) login_required decorator
6. Using flask-SQLalchemy's create_db yo build the database from your model
7. Using flask-SQLalchemy's db.session to set/get data from the db

For what it's worth, I really think The Flask Mega-Tutorial would be helpful.

UPDATE: Here is [a minimal example](https://gist.github.com/mjlavin80/c3784628b863791fc71ca5a8e4dd8c09) using a dictionary as a toy database. A few things about this example ...

1. If you run main.py and go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/token?username=admin&password=somepassword you will see the working get example
2. If you go to http://127.0.0.1:5000, click on "hello_world", click "post", and then click "try it out," you can enter a username and a password, and those will be added to the mock database.
3. After adding a username and password, you can go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/token?username=[]&password=[] except replace brackets with that new username and password. If you shutdown the server, the usernames and passwords won't be saved since it's just updating a dictionary.

Hopefully, all this helps ... once you've edited the app like this, it should be easier to debug issues that aren't related to username and password authentication.

Comment: I added my `user_db` schema, I am expecting the simplest way to make this work. as you can see, I simplified my implementation, so your possible input would be appreciated. Could you point me out how to make my code works and get some updated output?

Comment: I understand and appreciate your desire for a simplified version. To make things even simpler, how about coding up an example where your "database" is just a python dictionary in the code block with keys/values for username, credentials, etc? If you want to model read and write operations, maybe use sqlite?

Comment: I am open to hearing your thought. I am not comfortable with using SQLite. Can you share if you have updated answer via collab.

Comment: I mean use sqlite just for testing. The cool thing about sqlalchemy is that you can swap out the database and it still works.

Comment: would it be possible to reproduce with code? let's say just use [my backend service code](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/1c1f78f078a850674dd75c2a10f58def). thanks

Comment: @MattL. I guess beyond_infinity's last comment (question) is how to replace the DB with a python dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to implement a token based implementation similar to [JWT authorization](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

#### JWT in general

What JWT is all about is nicely summarized at [docs.nginx.com > JWT authorization](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-jwt-authentication/) which says

> JWT is data format for user information in the OpenID Connect standard, which is the standard identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. Deployers of APIs and microservices are also turning to the JWT standard for its simplicity and flexibility. With JWT authentication, a client provides a JSON Web Token, and the token will be validated against a local key file or a remote service.

You do not necessarily have to do the JWT on webserver level, but I usually prefer to do authentication on web server level in order to nicely split data (aka endpoints) and security.

Let us now focus on JWT with flask. The 
[blog.teclacode.com](https://blog.tecladocode.com/simple-jwt-authentication-with-flask-jwt/) nicely summarizes the work flow [comments by me]:

> 1. User provides their username and password [to an extraordinary endpoint]
>
> [The next 3 steps happen within that extraordinary endpoint].
>
> 2. We verify they are correct inside our Flask app
> 3. We generate a JWT which contains the user's ID.
> 4. We send that to the user.
> 5. Whenever the user makes a request to our application, they must send us the JWT we generated earlier.

I guess your challenge spans steps 1 through 4. Step 5 you seem to have implemented already: It is the un-secured endpoint(s) **plus** an additional, mandatory POST-parameter `token`. Those endpoints will give back data to the client once a valid token is provided. In other words: Each ordinary endpoint calls a function which validates a given token. Is this understanding correct? Is step 5 already working for you?

I never implemented JWT with python, but a [quick search for packages with JWT in their names](https://pypi.org/search/?q=jwt) give me the impressions that there are many ready-to-use token generators out there you "just" have to configure.

#### Dive into your code

A couple of questions about your code:

1. Do you really want to hard-code your secret key inside your code? That is a major security flaw, since you will have key disclosed in all your GIT commits etc.
2. Your entire code at GIT is not easy to access since there are some syntax errors in some files which prevent a full text search, the error message reads:

   > We can make that file beautiful and searchable if some errors are corrected.
3. Where and how is `user_db` defined? You mentioned that in a comment, but I cannot find that elsewhere. It would be helpful to have a paragraph on this in your question.
4. I guess that `http://127.0.0.1:5000/token` is an endpoint which provides the token, but I do not fully understand from the question in its current form where the endpoint `/token` is implemented.

Comment: @beyond_inifinity I saw that you tried to edit in answers to my question, but those where deleted, I fear. Maybe you could just answer my questions (1) to (4) as briefly as separate comments here.